# VBA returning result to different sheet in excel

Tags: vba

The coding works below but the value is showing on the wrong sheet. Can you help guide me to be able to have this value show up on a different sheet. i need the value to show up on Sheet2.

```
Sub showRandomWord()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim stRow As Long, endRow As Long, dataCol As Long
Dim dispRow As Long, dispCol As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
stRow = 2
dataCol = 1
dispRow = 2
dispCol = 4

With ws
    endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, dataCol).End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(dispRow, dispCol).Value = _
      .Cells(Application.RandBetween(stRow, endRow), dataCol).Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want it on `Sheet2`, why are you specifying `Sheet1` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set another variable for Sheet2 and set the cell value. Currently, you're accessing the same sheet to set a cell value and determine the random value to populate it with. Something like the following should work:

```
Sub showRandomWord()
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim stRow As Long, endRow As Long, dataCol As Long
Dim dispRow As Long, dispCol As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
stRow = 2
dataCol = 1
dispRow = 2
dispCol = 4

With ws
    endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, dataCol).End(xlUp).Row
End With

ws2.Cells(dispRow, dispCol).Value = ws.Cells(Application.RandBetween(stRow, endRow), dataCol).Value

End Sub
```